# matlab uitable blink in one computer but stop blinking in another one

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-uitable

I want to display uitable in matlab GUI.(uitable data is not fix it is going to update in 15 stage).
when i run my code in my laptop my monitor is not flicker, but when i run same code in another laptop it start blinking.
i want to know the cause of this problem(i mean the code not changed only ,i run it in another computer).
note:i guess it is related to CPU clock  but i am not sure.

Comment: i don't understand why people downvote me.i ask a logical question not a spam one????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not related to CPU or laptop graphic card.  it is about matlab version.i write my original code in matlab 2013a but when i run it in matlab 2009 ,it had problem n displaying uitable but in matlab 2012 or newer version that problem solved and the blinking did not occur.